# is there a way to make inline images responsive when using action mailer to send emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the action mailer, i am adding inline image as shown below

```
  def welcome_email(m)
    attachments.inline["banner.png"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/banner.png")
    mail(to: m, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
```

The email view looks as follows

```
<%= image_tag(attachments['banner.png'].url) %>

<p> Thanks for purchasing with us! </p>
```

Now the problem is that the image displayed in the email is the original size and it becomes too big. Even if i set a fixed width then in mobile screen it will be out of screen. So, i was wondering whether it is possible to make the image responsive just like bootstrap "img-responsive" tag so that the image shown is proper size in devices of different screen sizes.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the image `width` to `100%` using inline style.

Comment: thanks! this did it. does 100% fit the parent container?

Comment: Yes, it takes the width of the parent container.